# How to ignore errors in pandas.to_numeric() AND change str to int

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have an unexpected response from pandas.to_numeric().
If I use to_numeric

```py
    a = pd.Series(['1', '2', '3', np.nan])
    b = pd.to_numeric(a, downcast='integer', errors='ignore')
    print([type(each) for each in b])
```

response is:`[float, float, float, float]`

but if I have real str in series, like

```py
    a = pd.Series(['1', '2', '3', np.nan, 'a'])
    b = pd.to_numeric(a, downcast='integer', errors='ignore')
    print([type(each) for each in b])
```

it returns `[str, str, str, float, str]`

Doc says:

> If ‘ignore’, then **invalid parsing** will return the input

And I think that invalid parsing is only 'a', so I should get: `[float, float, float, float, str]`

the question is how to fix it and get `[float, float, float, float, str]`

Comment: I think it happens because there are 3 types: int, float, and str. I can handle even int of float, but not all str.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is use `errors='coerce'` with replace missing values to original values - so last `a` is in final `Series`:

```
a = pd.Series(['1', '2', '3', np.nan, 'a'])
b = pd.to_numeric(a, errors='coerce').fillna(a)
print([type(each) for each in b])
[<class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>]
```

Another idea is use function with `try-exception` block:

```
a = pd.Series(['1', '2', '3', np.nan, 'a'])

def func(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except Exception:
        return x

b = a.apply(func)
print([type(each) for each in b])
[<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>]
```

If possible integers with floats values in string representation:

```
a = pd.Series(['1', '2', '3.3', np.nan, 'a'])

def func(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except Exception:
        try:
            return float(x)
        except Exception:
            return x

b = a.apply(func)
print([type(each) for each in b])
[<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! But will not help if i have different strings in series like 'a', 'b' etc.

Comment: @Pruntoff - Why do you think so?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `apply`:

```
print(a.apply(lambda x: float(x) if str(x).isdigit() else x))
```

Output:

```
0      1
1      2
2      3
3    NaN
4      a
dtype: object
```

And:

```
print([type(i) for i in a.apply(lambda x: float(x) if str(x).isdigit() else x)])
```

Output:

```
[<class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>]
```